# .NET Byte Array COM casting issue

Tags: c#, casting, com

I have a dynamic method call to a COM object. When I try returning the result as byte[], I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[*]' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That will happen if you've created an array with a non-zero lower bound. What is the COM object doing?

Comment: It is retrieving a document from a storage provider as a byte[] array. This COM component is a blackbox. No access to the source. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM object method in your case seems to return a non-zero lower bound array. You can create a normal byte array and then copy the data from the first array like this:

```
var comArray = (Array)(object)comObject.CallToComObject();

byte[] data = new byte[comArray.Length];

Array.Copy(comArray, data, data.Length);
```

I am not sure if there is a way to avoid copying.

**EDIT:**

For a reason unknown to me, if the non-zero lower bound array is returned in a dynamic way, i.e, the signature of `CallToComObject` has a `dynamic` return value type, then an exception will be thrown if we simply try to cast it as `Array`. Casting it to an `object` first seems to solve the problem. I don't know why.

Comment: Failing on line 2 above, with same exception reported previously. I don't have var comArray, I have dynamic comArray.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c, I updated the answer, try to cast the return value to `object` and then to `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jon Skeet for the tip.

Once I understood what the problem was, didn't take long to find the solution. Thanks to this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Aug/26/Accessing-a-SafeArray-Result-from-a-COM-Call-in-C

The fixed code:

```
                    object fileData = _imageServerApplication.GetActualFile();
                    Array fileDataArray = (Array) fileData;
                    byte[] fileDataBytes = new byte[fileDataArray.Length];
                    fileDataArray.CopyTo(fileDataBytes, 0);
```